# Vcpkg package(s) missing on this computer

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

hopefully someone can help me on this. I have cloned azure-iot-sdk-c from Github and attempting to compile the iothub_II_telemetry_sample but am getting this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This project references Vcpkg package(s) that are missing on this computer. For more information, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/doc/setting_up_vcpkg.md. The missing file is include\azureiot\iothub.h.  D:\Azure\SDK\azure-iot-sdk-c\iothub_client\samples\iothub_ll_telemetry_sample\windows\iothub_ll_telemetry_sample.vcxproj    D:\Azure\SDK\azure-iot-sdk-c\iothub_client\samples\iothub_ll_telemetry_sample\windows\iothub_ll_telemetry_sample.vcxproj    200

I have followed the link provided in the error and installed vcpkg but still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT SDK uses many libraries (a few from Nuget packages and a few references such as MXchip etc) and you are using the C SDK of azure IoT sample on Windows, so to smooth installation of the required libraries you need vcpkg. Following is the link to install vcpkg, Once you install vcpkg, delete the Temp files and re-start your computer.

[Install vcpkg manager on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.\vcpkg.exe install azure-iot-sdk-c:x64-windows
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?